# store value of zero in zero array in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, zero

I need to store some values of certain size (`nsents`) into a variable like `scount` below. This array stores numbers (`scores`) and later the values in the variable `scount` will be divided with those of a similar array in order to get total scores.  Some of these values (`scores`) are zero. During scoring, not all of the indexes in the array are considered. The positions with 0 score are taken as 'empty' whereas actually the index was considered. I could change the size of the array but that won't work for the rest of my code.

```
scount = zeros(1,nsents);
```

If I ignore the zeros with something like

```
totalscores(totalscores==0) = [];
```

then along with the indexes that were not used I ignore those that were used but had zero score. Do you have any idea how I could solve this problem ? I am very new to Matlab so I apologize if my question is not very clear. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to solve.First,find the position where scount is not zero,the code is:

```
LL=find(scount~=0);
```

then,scoring the non-zeros elements only.For example,the scoring function is score=1./scount,the code is:

```
score=zeros(1,nsents);
score(LL)=1./scount(LL);
```

so,with the help of position variable LL,the scoring process has nothing to do with the scounts that are zero.
Hope it's helpful.Thanks.

Comment: that helped!Thanks.So,for example I have one var thatstores'counts' of how many times e.g.some items appear in an image: counts=zeros(1, nitems) and another that stores if some of these were noticed:scores=zeros(1,nitems).Then, I want to plot the mean scores:scores/counts. Is it correct to do:scores(non-zero positions in counts)/counts(no-zeros)? For example, is it correct to 1.find in counts the 'filled' indexes and match them to scores: score_index=find(counts~=0);  
score=scores(score_index); and 2. to delete then zeros from counts like that: counts(counts==0) = [];Thanks a lot for the help